# How to close a QDialog that uses a different ui file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdialog

I've been trying to close a QDialog that uses a separate ui file. The dialog is used in a slot of a different class (TaskManager). Sorry for the question but I couldn't find a workaround anywhere.

I'm creating a ToDo App as a University project (first year, first time using C++ and Qt): as the user clicks on the "Add Task" button in the TaskManager, the dialog is shown. The user inserts the tasks attributes in the dialog and then I take that data to create a Task object (different class) that is shown in the TaskManager (works fine if I close the dialog manually).

This is a code snippet of the creation of the dialog:

```
void TaskManager::on_pushButton_addTask_clicked()
{
    Ui::AddTask addTaskDialog; // addTaskDialog takes the Ui of the file AddTask.ui
    QDialog dialog;
    addTaskDialog.setupUi(&dialog);
    dialog.exec(); // shows the dialog
    [More Code]
}
```

I wanted to close the QDialog when the user clicks on QDialogButtonBox:

- ok -> closes the dialog
- cancel -> closes and deletes the dialog.

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work (I get this build issue: "No matching member function for call to 'connect'):

```
QPushButton* ok = addTaskDialog.buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, dialog.close());
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, this, dialog.close());` - your connect is wrong, you don't pass a pointer to a member function as forth parameter but the return value of dialog.close(). Also the context is wrong -> `connect(ok, &QPushButton::clicked, &dialog, QQDialog::close)`.

btw: Your whole approach on how to create this dialog looks fishy - better create a new class derived from QDialog and do the stuff in there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @chehrlic , it partially solved the problem!
The connect is now correct, it doesn't show any syntax error. Unluckily it doesn't work: when I click on the Ok button nothing happens. I also tried changing the button from QDialogButtonBox to QPushButton but I get the same problem.
I don't know what's wrong with this code, sorry, it's my first programming project.
CppCheck gives me this alert: "Either the condition 'ok' is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference: ok.".
Thank you for your suggestion to create a new class, I'll rethink about it

Comment: You have to do the connect *before* your call exec().

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works!!!
For a newbie just like me, you have been very very helpful!!